# Can you convert the <video> part of this code into a youtube iframe embed

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have this piece of code that I'm using for an intro video and it all works perfectly alongside my progress bars for loading, however, I've just realised the client I'm putting it into can't use mp4 files. I've uploaded the video to youtube and would like to just use an youtube  embed instead of the local source.

```
<video class="introVideo" id="introVideo" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("introVideo");

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 32: //SpaceBar
        myVideo.muted = !myVideo.muted;
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

I used my incredibly basic knowledge to attempt this but I'm pretty sure I'm just practising wishful thinking and it won't work like this.

```
<iframe class="introVideo" id="introVideo" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2x18zIJb-YY?autoplay=1&mute=1&%3Fvq=hd1080&;controls=0;&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen="";></iframe>
</video>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("introVideo");

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 32: //SpaceBar
        myVideo.muted = !myVideo.muted;
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Forgot to put exactly what I want from this. I essentially just want a youtube embedded video with no pointer-events (done in css) so it cant be played/paused/fullscreened or anything, but then I also want people to have the option of muting the video's audio with "spacebar" when they're loading into the game.

Comment: You cannot do that in css or javascript, an iframe is on their server.

Comment: You can use the iframe API for what your doing with muting https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and to fix pointer events just place a div over the top and fiddle z-index's

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh wow, had no idea all this was available. Could you maybe give me an example of how it would look? Does it use a similar function for keypresses etc

Comment: `function onKeyDown(event) {
             switch (event.keyCode) {
                 case 32: //SpaceBar                    
                     if (muted) {
                         player.unmute() = false
                         muted = true;
                     } else {
                         player.mute():Void
                         muted = false;
                     }
                     break;`

Comment: I'm not massively educated on JS so i'm just spitballing here from various code i've found online

Comment: Still haven't been able to get it working, just not sure where to start with youtubes iframe api

Comment: There is an example of how it looks like on the linked iframe_api_reference page, just copy the topmost html code play with it. here some quick and dirty fiddle for you with a copy of the linked stuff plus catching the space key. https://jsfiddle.net/7mLx2h0z/1/ note that when the focus is on the video, the space key event is not forwarded to your code, the player will pause instead of mute